# How do I toggle text and colour together in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, text, colors, toggle

I'd like to toggle certain words in a text string. I'd like the words to toggle (between RED and GREEN in my example) - I can do this no problem. But I'd also like the colour to match the words and change from red to green as the words change.
Thank you all for your help :-)

Here is my code to toggle the words:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body> 
<div>
<p  style="font-size:30px">

<span>I want to toggle (and change colour) Red and Green:</span>
<span class="ISHide" onclick="toggle1(this)"><a href="#" >RED</a></span>

</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle1 (t1) {
if (t1.childNodes[0].innerHTML == "RED") {
    t1.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "GREEN";
} else {
    t1.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "RED"; 
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `t1.childNodes[0].style.color = "red"`

Comment: You're missing a `</div`> and can you provide your .css?

Comment: Here's a version without inline code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rucbw6k2/

Comment: @King11, thanks I've edited to include the missing div.

Comment: @king11, sorry, not sure what .css I should have. What I have posted is all I have - it works as I've described, but doesn't change the colours.

Comment: I don't need the css. I just saw that you had a css class named `ISHide` and wanted to see it so I can see the full code. But its not needed to solve your problem

Comment: @ChrisG, sorry, I'm not sure how to incorporate your snippet, can you expand please?

Comment: @ChrisG, your jsfiddle solution worked great and I was able to duplicate it in my editor - thank you.

Comment: @Michael I've updated my answer to show you a JavaScript way to solve your problem and a JQuery way

Comment: @King11, yes I see now, thanks, it works great and follows logically from my original code. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Michael No problem. Glad I could help. Just mark it as the accepted answer so that this question can become resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your functionality at a pure JavaScript level and not change too much of your original code:

Just add `t1.childNodes[0].style.color = "GREEN";` in your `if` statement.

and `t1.childNodes[0].style.color = "RED";` in your `else` statement.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sL4gabvr/

Or If you wanted some JQuery in your code for your solution to toggle the words and colors:

I've changed your `onlick` to a JQuery click selector and gave your `a` an id attribute.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snqhk8Lj/

I tried not to change too much of your code while still making it legible and hopefully easy to understand.